# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error

Tags: java, bukkit

I recently bumped into an error when running my runnable which updates the location of minecarts. `Main.UvehicleLocation2` is a `HashMap`

```
[22:36:59] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 607/WARN]: Exception in thread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 607" 
[22:36:59] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 607/WARN]: org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException: Plugin CreativeControlByKubqoA v2.2.3 generated an exception while executing task 3019245
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:56)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1429)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1453)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:141)
at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:177)
at me.kubqoa.creativecontrol.tasks.VehiclesUpdateDB.run(VehiclesUpdateDB.java:19)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53)
... 3 more
```

This is the code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    List<Location> locations1 = new ArrayList<Location>(Main.UvehiclesLocation2.keySet());
    for (Location location : locations1) {
        VehicleHelper.updateVehicle(location,Main.UvehiclesLocation2.get(location));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Main.UvehiclesLocation2.keySet()` is being changed while you are copying it into the new array list. You'd need exclusive access to that instance while you copy it. (Or use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, for instance).

Comment: Like change the type of `UvehiclesLocation2` from `HashMap` to `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Yes. If you need to iterate it and update it at the same time, you can use `ConcurrentHashMap`. In particular [iterating `keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet()) is guaranteed not to throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

`Main.UvehiclesLocation2.keySet()` is being changed while you are copying it into the new array list.

You either need exclusive access to that instance while you copy it (e.g. using a `synchronized` block), or you can change `Main.UvehiclesLocation2` to be a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead. [From the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet()):

> The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

Comment: I changed the type to `ConcurrentHashMap` but now when trying to access the HashMap in another part of code using `if (Main.UvehiclesLocation2.containsKey(location)) location=Main.UvehiclesLocation2.get(location);` it throws error `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UvehiclesLocation2`

Comment: Sounds like you need to recompile your code.

Comment: That does not work, I did the same error.